# how to start nfc android

Tags: android, nfc

Hi I have android galaxy S (os 2.3.3 ) that is not nfc enable . Now in my project i have to work with nfc.
 how to intract with mifare card with my device is it possible or not or it will work with only nfc enable mobile (nuxus S ) only.I have mifare desifire 2k card also ? 
I m struggling with this from 2 days plese help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Nexus S is can read and write card mifare. Buy using the NXP Tag Writer or you can develop yourself or using this source of stickynote of

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=49L7z3rxz4Q

But i not yet done with p2p with nfc reader and nexus s.

Answer (score 1):

Buy a Nexus S. If your phone does not have an NFC reader/writer installed there is really no way to add one.

Comment: First thanks for quick response .but in some video of google violet introduction  i have listen that if we dont have nfc enable phone then through some chip we can make it nfc enable ?

Comment: That chip would probably be just a NFC-enabled smart card, not a reader/writer. You will be able to use it to pay for things, but not control it from the phone, and certainly not read other cards with it. If you want to do NFC development, what you need is a device with a built-in NFC reader/writer and associated drivers (such as a Nexus S).

Comment: That chip in the Nexus-S will read all NFC tag-types and ISO15693 tags just fine.